# How to move items in card using bootstrap-3

Tags: html, css

So i have this card, i am not sure how to pace items in it the way i want. In the html code i have used bootstrap-3. Css is just noob basic pixels movement.

> ```
>  <body>
>         <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up">
>     <div class="front">
>       <img class="girlimg" src="girl.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
>       <h2 class="activname">Guided hiking tours</h2>
>       <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
>         SEE DETAILS
>       </button>
>       <div class="details">
>         <div class="duration">
>           <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration</i>
>         </div>
>         <div class="people">
>           <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
>           <p>Max adults:10</p>
>         </div>
>         <div class="kids">
>           <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
>           <p>Max children:3</p>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>   <br />
> ```

Comment: "i am not sure how to pace items in it the way i want" -- How do you want to place items?

Comment: Photo on the top left corner, all the details in the right of the photo, h2 and button under the photo, all into the card. I have no idea how to place them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.front {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up">
      <div class="front">
        <div>
          <img class="girlimg" src="https://picsum.photos/250/150" alt="asdasda" />
          <h2 class="activname">Guided hiking tours</h2>
          <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
          SEE DETAILS
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <div class="duration">
            <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration</i>
          </div>
          <div class="people">
            <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
            <p>Max adults:10</p>
          </div>
          <div class="kids">
            <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
            <p>Max children:3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This just uses flexbox, which is incredibly useful. If you want to learn more CSS-Tricks has a good article: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I cannot figure out what have you did, so you added more scripts and a display flex ? How can i make exact thing for more than one card ?

Comment: All I did was wrap the image, h2, and button in a div, and then set the container div to `display: flex;`

Comment: The scripts are just bootstrap and jquery, you don't need to add them.